# Default Sitelogo (image) for googlebot?

Tags: googlebot

Hy

How i can add a default image for my site to display in the google search results when i type the name of the site to search for?
Currently every few weeks a different image/picture is displaying, current one picture from my news.

Google Search result =
**https://www.may_site.com [ logo ]**

Currently I added a logo to my first link at the top of the page..

```
<a href="/" title="HOME"><img src="/images/logo.png" width="70" height="70" alt="Sitename Logo"></a>
```

Sometimes no picture is visible :/

Answer (score 0):

Google reads `meta` tags in your page `<head></head>` to understand what you want to show in search results.
As far as I know there is not an official "logo" or "image" tag that Google support, but is smart enough to understand that "og:image" is the page image.

```html
<head>
    <meta name="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg">
</head>
```

You can read more here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/special-tags

And you can find a comprehensive list of `meta` here
https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/1978404

Comment: Note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: You're right, good catch @Rob. I've copied/pasted without noticing it. I've edited the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Google supports defining your logo in structured data. Here is their documentation on it:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/logo

However, I think you are talking more about a general image related to a page.

Using the og:image meta tag mentioned by @supermod can be a hint. Google also understands images in certain structured data types like recipes, products, articles etc. Their gallery shows what structured data can cause rich snippets like an image:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/search-gallery

But it is not necessary to provide metadata or structured data to get images in the search results. Sometimes Google just picks one from the page.